# Open Modal by clicking the link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code below to show data from mysql in modal popup. Everything works very well, but I want to open modal by clicking the link instead the button.

Is this even possible, because I have POST method in javascript?

Any advice?

Thank you!

My code:

```
<input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="view_data" />


 <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  

 <script>  

      $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(employee_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"select.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
                          $('#dataModal').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
      });  

 </script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565247/bootstrap-modal-link

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen This is not the same. I fetch the data from mysql via javascript and php.. On the link above is just simple html/css example.

Comment: Well the link is how to do it with a link, just add the id to the link and your good to go.  try `<a class="view_data" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" >view</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `button` use `<a>` like below. You are writing the jquery click event based on the class `.view_data`. If you apply the same `class` and `id` for a link it will work.

```
<a id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="view_data">view</a>
```