# instead of taking to a different page, open page in modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure if this is possible but what I'm trying to do is when user clicks a button then instead of taking the user to a different page, I want the new page to be opened in a modal, and be active there. I'm using twitter bootstrap. is it possible to do that?

bootstrap modal:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my link:

```
<a href="{% url 'comment_new' post.id %}">hello</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565247/bootstrap-modal-link)

Comment: @MoshFeu not the same one, I saw that before posting. the post doesn't take it to the different page tho, there's no a href="#" but I have some link inside href

Comment: So what do you want to do with the link (`href` attribute)?

Comment: @MoshFeu send it to a new page

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When a user clicks on the link, you want to open a modal or open the link's page?

Comment: @MoshFeu the modal is opened and inside that modal the user can write comment.  the comment forum is linked to different page such as www.abc.com/comment  while the post is in www.abc.com/post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194668/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-rosababy).